# Can something be "blacker" than something else? How common are single-word comparatives and superlatives for color-designating adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, comparisons, superlative-degree, colors

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/black) implies that the comparative and superlative for *black* are *blacker* and *blackest*. However, my native British colleague says he would never used *blacker*, only *more black*.

How common is using single-word comparatives and superlatives for color-designating adjectives? Is it used for some colors only (like *white*) whilst not for others (like *black*)?

Would you use the following sentences, or would you replace the single-word comparatives and superlatives with their compound version (*more ...*, *most ...*)?

> Our toner is *blacker* than the ones from other companies.
>
> Eco-terrorists fight for *greener* world.
>
> After using this toothpaste your teeth will be *whiter*.
>
> He is undoubtedly a nobleman with the *bluest* possible blood.

Comment: [Neither black nor white are colors !](http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-design/are-black-and-white-colors) ;)

Comment: @YohannV. technically you are right :) but from the language point of view they *are* colors.

Comment: The answers to your (two) questions are *yes* and *very common*, respectively.

Comment: In brightest day, in **blackest** night, / No evil shall escape my sight. / Let those who worship evil's might / Beware my power--Green Lantern's light.

Comment: @VampDuc: in your example I would follow the YohannV's comment that *black* is not a color, because in this collocation it is rather a synonym for *darkest night* - expressing literally and explicitly (in the very physical meaning) just the **lack of light** :)

Comment: @YohannV., I find that hard to believe. --- "What color is your car?" "Oh, it doesn't have a color." ---- "What color paint do you want?" "I don't want paint with a color." ---- etc.

Comment: @PaulDraper "Which color did you chose for your car?" "I didn't, I picked black !" Admit that you cannot talk about *shades* of black. It can be another color (obsidian) or grey, which is a lighter black but you can't go for **50 shades of black**. (I'm pretty proud of me :3)

Comment: The word color has a dozen or more definitions, and black IS a color in at least a couple of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using colors as adjectives, I would use the adjectives rules.

The [basic rule](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-superlative-form.htm) for adjectives is :

> - **short** adjectives: add ["-er",] "-est"
> - **long** adjectives: use ["more",] "most"

And *short* and *long* adjectives definition :

> **Short adjectives**
>
> > 1. *one syllable adjectives* : old, fast
> > 2. *2-syllable adjectives ending in -y* : happy, easy
>
> **Long adjectives**
>
> > 1. *2-syllable adjectives not ending in -y* : modern, pleasant
> > 2. *all adjectives of 3 or more syllables* :    expensive, intellectual

---

#### Ngram

But it's true that the *"most black"* tends to be [increasingly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blacker%20than%2C%20more%20black%20than%2C%20blackest%2C%20most%20black&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblacker%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20black%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblackest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20black%3B%2Cc0), I would say that is an incorrect usage.

Comment: There is a missing rule for 2-syllables-long adjectives in your definition :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Read again the rules ^^'. A 2-syllables-long adjective ending in -y will be a **short adjective** and a 2-syllables-long adjective not ending with -y will be a **long adjective**. Then you follow the *basic rule*.

Comment: I am not clear how to read "2. syllable adjectives" - do you mean "bullet nr. 2", or do you mean "2-syllables-long"? Because the dot usually marks items in a numbered list... but then the rest doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Oh I see what your problem is, **-** became **.** and I missed the syllables numbers. I edited to make it clearer, ask me if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

For every one of your examples, [your usage is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blacker%2Cmore+black%2Cgreener%2Cmore+green%2Cwhiter%2Cmore+white%2Cbluer%2Cmore+blue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblacker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20black%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreener%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20green%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhiter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20white%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbluer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20blue%3B%2Cc0) than its "more X" counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

The *er* suffix  can be added to many words to indicate a superlative, such as *faster*, *stronger* etc, it's not specific to colours. Something like *whiter* is very commonly used, as in advertising for toothpaste. *whiter* is more succinct and effective than *more white* in this context

The exception is words ending in a vowel, such as purple, *orange*. Here you would say *more orange*

Comment: *faster* is comparative, not superlative

Comment: What about *blue*? Ending in a vowel... but other people say that *bluer* and *bluest* is OK.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that one, bluer. I guess even oranger is correct, but sounds odd.

Answer (score 1):

"[A Whiter Shade of Pale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Whiter_Shade_of_Pale)" is apparently,

> ... the most-played record by British broadcasting of the past 70 years.
>
> Reid got the title and starting point for the song at a party. He overheard someone at the party saying to a woman, "You've turned a whiter shade of pale," and the phrase stuck in his mind.

---

I'd use "more" instead of "-er" only in the following context: "It's more blue than green" or "It's more black than red" – if I want to imply that "it's not green", or "so black that it's not red".